# Cocoapod framework not found

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

This is the content of my "Podfile":

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target "yame" do
    pod 'ImageLoader'
    pod 'KYDrawerController'
    pod 'JLToast', '~> 1.3'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'

    pod 'Bolts'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
end

target "yameTests" do
    pod 'ImageLoader'
    pod 'KYDrawerController'
    pod 'JLToast', '~> 1.3'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'

    pod 'Bolts'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
end
```

Suddenly for no apparent reason I started getting an error: **No such module 'ImageLoader'**.

I believe this error happens for any of  the other modules in the project.
I looked at many solutions in Google. None seems to help.

Comment: Can it be that you opened your Projectfile instead of the Workspace? And another question: why do you ahve all you Pods in your project target AND in your test target?

Comment: I have the same kind of issue for some other library. It appears while building and it resolves if I try hit build and clean couple of times..

Comment: I always work with the project file and not with the workspace, at least as far as I recall. I also tried to work with the workspace but got about 20 errors on the framework code itself. Pods are in both target and test due to tests I did. I removed the test target.

Comment: @senty I tried clean & then build, it doesn't do much...

Answer (score 0):

The `No such module 'ImageLoader'` error is shown when you execute `pod install`?

- if is the same libraries for both targets, why separate?.
- You are sure that you ios platform is `'8.0'`

> You can try it in another project, because sometimes setting pods in the project is corrupt and is very difficult to fix that.

i think that you can test with only the next in your `Podfile`.

```
pod 'ImageLoader'
pod 'KYDrawerController'
pod 'JLToast', '~> 1.3'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
pod 'Bolts'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'

use_frameworks!
```